# group different columns together into list of struct struct based on suffix list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have a dataFrame that looks like:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key1_suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2_suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key1_suffix2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- key2_suffix2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- suffix2: string (nullable = true)
```

How can we convert this into another dataframe like this:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: struct (nullable = true)
 |     |-- suffix1: struct (nullable = true)
 |     |     |-- key1_suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |     |     |-- key2_suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |     |     |-- suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |     |-- suffix2: struct (nullable = true)
 |     |     |-- key1_suffix2: string (nullable = true)
 |     |     |-- key2_suffix2: string (nullable = true)
 |     |     |-- suffix2: string (nullable = true)
```

Input array with suffixes will be already given.
example inputSuffix=["suffix1","suffix2"]

This is needed in spark scala code. Spark=3.1 and scala = 2.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use struct() function to group columns into 1 nested columns:

```
// test data
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
  ("2", "aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff")
).toDF("id", "key1_suffix1", "key2_suffix1", "suffix1", "key1_suffix2", "key2_suffix2", "suffix2")

// Processing
val res = df.withColumn("tags", struct(struct("key1_suffix1", "key2_suffix1", "suffix1").as("suffix1"),
  struct("key1_suffix2", "key2_suffix2", "suffix2").as("suffix2")))
  .drop("key1_suffix1", "key2_suffix1", "suffix1", "key1_suffix2", "key2_suffix2", "suffix2")

res.printSchema()


root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- suffix1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- key1_suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key2_suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- suffix1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- suffix2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- key1_suffix2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key2_suffix2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- suffix2: string (nullable = true)
```

**UPDATE**

This can be done dynamically using a list of columns, if you value in the list that doesn't exist in the dataframe you can remove them to make sure you will not get some errors:

```
val inputSuffix = Array("suffix1", "suffix2", "suffix3")
val inputSuffixFiltred = inputSuffix.filter(c => df.columns.contains(s"key1_$c") && df.columns.contains(s"key2_$c") && df.columns.contains(c))
val tagsCol = inputSuffixFiltred.map(c => struct(s"key1_$c", s"key2_$c", c).as(c))
val colsToDelete = inputSuffixFiltred.flatMap(c => Seq(s"key1_$c", s"key2_$c", c))
val res = df.withColumn("tags", struct(tagsCol: _*)).drop(colsToDelete: _*)
res.printSchema()
```

Comment: But this needs to be done for suffix given in input list. There can be any number of columns with those suffix. So it needs to be in more dynamic fashion.

Basically, group all columns ending with suffix present in the array together.

Comment: Thanks, how can we rename that struct with suffix1 ?

Comment: @YashaJadwani what name you want ? you can rename it in the .as(c) part

Comment: And what if the input array is something like ["suffix1","suffix2","suffix3"]. It fails here with `cannot resolve "key1_suffix"`. How to fix that?

Comment: Your column name is key1_suffix1 and not key1_suffix, if you have the columns key1_suffix, key2_suffix, suffix1, then the list should be Array("suffix1", "suffix2", "suffix")

Comment: So if i have array=["suffix1","suffix2","suffix3"]. But there is no column with suffix3, it fails with error `cannot resolve "key1_suffix3"`. How can we fix that?

Comment: In that case your list should be ["suffix1","suffix2"], why you want it to be ["suffix1","suffix2","suffix3"] ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251055/discussion-between-yasha-jadwani-and-abdennacer-lachiheb).